# opencv python detectMultiScale api

Tags: python, opencv

I was following this particular [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) on object detection.
He uses this version of detectMultiSacle function in his code, which allows him to adjust threshold for detection or something like that with rejectLevels and levelWeights:

> Python:

```
cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image,
rejectLevels, levelWeights[,
scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[,
minSize[, maxSize[,
outputRejectLevels]]]]]]) → objects
```

This is my code:

```
detectMultiScale(image=gray,
rejectLevels=rejectlevels,
levelWeights=levelweights)
```

But it gives the following error, which makes me confused:

```
 TypeError: 'rejectLevels' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I was trying to use `detectMultiScale(image, rejectLevels, levelWeights, scaleFactor)` originally, but it gives me error that says the fourth argument can't be float, which made suspect I wasn't using the function I thought I was using.

I use `pip` to install opencv-python which is version 3.3.0.9. I couldn't find any python documents other than this [webpage](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html).

Appreciate some help. Like where can I find documents for latest python api, or some experience with this particular function.

Comment: Use `help` in the interpreter.

Comment: wow, thanks, that's a really useful.

Comment: No problem. Also check out [`dir(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to find python documentation for OpenCV 3.3 but the OpenCV3.0 [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) show that detectMultiScale uses `ouputRejectLevels`. Try using that argument.

Here's their breakdown:

> Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize]]]]]) → objects
>
> Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale2(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize]]]]]) → objects, numDetections
>
> Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale3(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize[, outputRejectLevels]]]]]]) → objects, rejectLevels, levelWeights

Answer (score 0):

While the online documentation for the recent versions of OpenCV does not list information about the Python bindings, it is quite simple to find it -- it's embedded right in the Python module. At the least you will get the signatures of the methods in question.

Use the build-in [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) function to access it.

For example (not that this is OpenCV 3.1, so double check it locally):

```
>>> import cv2
>>> c = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
>>> help(c.detectMultiScale)
Help on built-in function detectMultiScale:

detectMultiScale(...)
    detectMultiScale(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize]]]]]) -> objects
```